# Variable changes after the size of a 2D array is increased

Tags: c

A word gets written to the 0th row and column of a 2D array. When I go to resize the array to get ready to store another word, I store the word at the 0th row and column into a temp variable. After I call the function that increases the size of the 2D array, the temp variable changes to something very strange. For example I passed in 'i' and after I increase the size of the rows, the variable temp that stored i changes. Why does this happen?

```
void make_row_decode_structure_bigger(int rows){
    printf("inside the making the rows bigger \n");
    int max_rows = rows+1;

    char **store = realloc( decode_structure, sizeof *decode_structure * (rows + 2) );
    printf("after a store has been assigned\n");    
    if (store){ 
        decode_structure = store;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){

            decode_structure[rows + i] = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    printf("end of making the rows increase\n");
    return;
    //decode_structure[max_rows][0] = '\0';
}

//other part of code
char* temp;
        strncpy(temp, decode_structure[0], 20);
        printf("this word %s is at the top of decode_structure\n", temp);
        printf("make the rows bigger is being called\n");
        make_row_decode_structure_bigger(num);
        printf("temp after make_row_decode_structure_biggeris called %s \n", temp);
```

this is the output:

this word i is at the top of decode_structure
make the rows bigger is being called
inside the making the rows bigger
after a store has been assigned
end of making the rows increase
temp after make_row_decode_structure_biggeris called Ó«

Comment: In `char* temp; strncpy(temp, decode_structure[0], 20);` the `temp` is uninitialised so it is undefined behaviour. It is using some random memory that is either being clobbered or is clobbering something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
char* temp;
strncpy(temp, decode_structure[0], 20);
```

you are using as the destination of the copy, an uninitialized pointer, which invokes Undefined Behavior (UB).

Use `char temp[20];` instead, or if you really want a pointer, then use malloc to dynamically allocate memory, that will be pointed by the pointer, like this: `char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);`.